# Construct input array to component ,data formatting in typescript(Anuglar/React)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below array is input of the component.if this input is passed to component output showing fine.

```
 const data = [
            ['Rank', 'Player', 'Player', 'Player'],
            ['1', 'sachin', 'dravid', 'ganguly'],
            ['2', 'pointhig', 'mcrath', 'warne'],
            ['3', 'sanath', 'murali', 'vaas'],
            ['4', 'akram', 'younis', 'akhamed'] 
        ]
```

But mine api respone is like below.I tried to convert the api to above  input data.Rank column should be auto increment. I tried to convert like above but i failed to convert .

```
0:Array(3)
    0:{fullname:'sachin'}
    1:{fullname:'dravid'}
    2:{fullname:'ganguly'}
1:Array(3)
    0:{fullname:'pointhig'}
    1:{fullname:'mcrath'}
    2:{fullname:'warne'}
2:Array(3)
    0:{fullname:'sanath'}
    1:{fullname:'murali'}
    2:{fullname:'vaas'}
3:Array(3)
    0:{fullname:'akram'}
    1:{fullname:'younis'}
    2:{fullname:'akhamed'}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const header = ["Rank", "Player", "Player", "Player"];
const data = [
  [{ fullname: "sachin" }, { fullname: "dravid" }, { fullname: "ganguly" }],
  [{ fullname: "pointhig" }, { fullname: "mcrath" }, { fullname: "warne" }],
  [{ fullname: "sanath" }, { fullname: "murali" }, { fullname: "vaas" }],
  [{ fullname: "akram" }, { fullname: "younis" }, { fullname: "akhamed" }]
];

const content = data.map((item, idx) => [
  (idx + 1).toString(),
  ...item.map(x => x.fullname)
]);
const result = [...[header], ...content];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested `map()`

```js
const arr = [[
    {fullname:'sachin'},
    {fullname:'dravid'},
    {fullname:'ganguly'}
],
    [{fullname:'pointhig'},
    {fullname:'mcrath'},
    {fullname:'warne'}],
[{fullname:'sanath'},
{fullname:'murali'},
{fullname:'vaas'}],

[{fullname:'akram'},
{fullname:'younis'},
{fullname:'akhamed'}]]

const res = arr.map((x, i) => [i + 1 ,...x.map(a => a.fullname)]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer with dynamic header size

```js
const base = [
  [{
    fullname: 'sachin'
  }, {
    fullname: 'dravid'
  }, {
    fullname: 'ganguly'
  }],
  [{
    fullname: 'pointhig'
  }, {
    fullname: 'mcrath'
  }, {
    fullname: 'warne'
  }],
  [{
    fullname: 'sanath'
  }, {
    fullname: 'murali'
  }, {
    fullname: 'vaas'
  }],
  [{
    fullname: 'akram'
  }, {
    fullname: 'younis'
  }, {
    fullname: 'akhamed'
  }],
];

const result = base.map((x, xi) => [
  xi + 1,
  ...x.map(y => y.fullname),
]);

result.unshift([
  'Rank',
  ...[...Array(result[0].length - 1)].map(_ => 'Player'),
])

console.log(result);
```